# Having trouble counting down and printing loops

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

So I need my code to print out in increments on 3 user inputs, I have a 2nd java file to use dot notation to execute methods from. So it's supposed to run kinda like this.

Pick > Starting Value - Pick Increment value - Pick > Ending Value
All these are user input and I need to have it if the starting value > then the ending then count up from starting value with user input increments. But if end

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class logic  {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

    //new scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Data
      char ch = 0;
      int start = 0; 
      int end = 0;
      int inc = 0;
      String printStr = "";
      final int SENTINEL = -1;
      String menu ="Looping (Demo)" +
                   "\nStart Value\t [S]" +
                   "\nIncrement value  [I]" +
                   "\nEnd Value\t [E]" + 
                   "\nFor Looping\t [F]" +
                   "\nQuit\t\t [Q]" +
                   "\nEnter Option > "; 

    while(ch != SENTINEL) {

    switch(ch) {
        case 'S':
        case 's':

            start = UtilsDM.readInt("Enter loop start value: ", false);      
            break;

        case 'I':
        case 'i':        
            inc = UtilsDM.readInt("Enter loop increment value: ", false);          
            break;   

        case 'E':
        case 'e':
            end = UtilsDM.readInt("Enter loops end value: ", false);
            break;      

        case 'F':
        case 'f': 
            if(start <= end){
                for (int i=start; i<=end; i+=inc) {                     
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }//end loop +
            }//end if
            else if(start >= end){ 
                for (int i=end; i<=start; i-=inc) {                
                    System.out.print(i + " ");                    
                }//end loop -
            }//end else if

            System.out.println("\n");                  
            break; 

        case 'Q':
        case 'q':
            System.out.println("Terminating upon user command.");
            System.exit(0);
            break; 

        default:
            System.out.println("Unrecognized character");
            break;
    }//end switch

    ch =  UtilsDM.readChar(menu, false);
   }//end loop







    //computations, algorithms

    //outputs, formatting, display
    } //end main  

}//end class
```

Comment: Where the for/ if /else go I think have to go where the case f switch is which I can only use 5

Comment: This looks like Java, not javascript. They're completely unrelated. As they say, "java is to javascript as car is to carpet".

Comment: Sorry noted will delete that. New to this so have yet to learn the difference :).

Comment: what do you need your code to increment and print out o.O?

Comment: So if your starting value is 0 your increments are 2 and your ending is 20     it needs to be 0 2 4 6 8 up to 20 but if it's starting at 20 and ending at 0 then it needs to be 20 18 16 till 0. I can make it go minus 1 by doing -- but I am not sure how to incorporate if the user puts -2 or like -7 in how to incorporate that.

Comment: 1) As a matter of style, don't put the `//endxx` comments in, especially since your editor is not going to be obliging and move them for you.  2) You're going to get much better results if you divorce the menu from the printing code.  For one thing, you can tell it to start looping without ever putting in the start/end values, which doesn't make much sense.  3) Positive ranges should be end-value exclusive.  4) Don't use `System.Exit(...)`, you should be setting your sentinel value (or really, marking a `running` Boolean false or something), to let the program exit gracefully.

Comment: This is an assignment that I am working on for class. And unfortunately I have to follow these guidelines he set out for us since he is really picky. As for as the //end, that is what he wants as far as noting standards. And the system.exit he didn't go over in lecture material so I am not sure how to gracefully exit a switch without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the case 'F' to as follows, i have commented the changes :-

```
 case 'F':
 case 'f': 
        if(start < end || (start < 0 && end < 0 && end > start))  // start < end or start = -3 and end = -7
        {
            for (int i=start; i<=end; i+=inc) 
            {                     
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
        else if(start > end || (start < 0 && end < 0 && start > end))  //  if start = - 7 and end = -3
        { 
            for (int i=end; i>=start; i-=inc) // should be greater than 
            {                
                System.out.print(i + " ");                    
            }
        }
        else if(start == end)
        {
          System.out.println(end);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I will eventually need to hire a tutor for this class lol

Comment: No probs @DaneMuller, i dont think so... you would get the hang of it as time goes by :) (if you dont stop programming)